# Trying to find the name of a really old UI design book by Apple

Tags: user-interface, mac-classic

This morning, I was reading a news article on Apple (either Snow Leopard or FCC), and I came across a part that referred to an old book by Apple (IIRC), that had two parts, and the first part was just on UI design. I was trying to get a copy of that book, but it seems I lost the link to the article. Does this book ring a bell with anyone, and if so, what's the title? (This book was published before 2000, maybe even before 1990, so if anyone recalls this book, congrats!, you have a great memory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to take a punt at either of these books.

Apple Computer Inc. (1985). Chapter Two: The Macintosh User-Interface Guidelines. In Inside Macintosh: Volume I

Apple Computer Inc. (1991). Chapter Two: User Interface Guidelines. In Inside Macintosh: Volume IV

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure this is what you are looking for but this book was written by Jef Raskin who worked for Apple at the time:

http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ISBN=0201379376/oweninkA/

Comment: If a book published in 2000 is "really old", then what does that make older books?

Comment: THat book was published long after he left Apple (bevause of rows with Steve Jobs)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be thinking of **[Bruce Tognazzini's *Tog on Interface*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201608421)**, written in 1992. This is a book by Apple's original designer. The first half of the whole book is indeed on interface design. (And even if it isn't the one you were looking for I found it to be a very interesting read.)